# Parsing xml with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing

I wan't to get all id's of this xml (the xml can't be changed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<List>
 <Person1>
    <Id>E00023</Id>
    <empName>Aadharsh</empName> 
 </Person1>
 <Person2>
    <Id>E00042</Id>
    <empName>Raksha</empName> 
 </Person2>
</List>
```

I tried following code, but I doesn't work :(
The Problem is that Person1 and Person2 are differnt names.
What I have to change to get all Id's?

```
$XMLfile = 'C:\test.xml'
[XML]$empDetails = Get-Content $XMLfile
 
foreach($module in $empDetails.List.$module){
Write-Host "Id :" $module.Id
}
```

With this code I get only the Id of Person1:

```
$XMLfile = 'C:\test.xml'
[XML]$empDetails = Get-Content $XMLfile
     
foreach($module in $empDetails.List.Person1){
Write-Host "Id :" $module.Id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I have to change?

First and foremost: You need to change `<Person1>` and `<Person2>` to `<Person>` in your XML. Don't use element names with a counter suffix, because that makes processing the XML unnecessarily hard (and because it is a completely pointless thing to do - if there are two persons described in the XML, then both of them are supposed to be `<Person>`).

Doing that makes accessing the XML easy and logical:

```
foreach ($person in $empDetails.List.Person) {
    Write-Host "Id :" $person.Id
}
```

Second: You need to change the way you read XML files. Don't ever use `Get-Content` to read XML files. Always create an XML document object and `.Load()` the XML via the file path.

```
$empDetails = New-Object xml
$empDetails.Load('C:\test.xml')
```

This makes sure that the file encoding is handled correctly (i.e. the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`). Using `Get-Content` will not do that, which can lead to broken data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately I cannot change the names of Person1 and Person2. I created this xml only to illustrate my Problem.

Is there a way to parse the xml with Person1 and Person2?

Comment: @Thomas You can use `$x.List.ChildNodes`. PowerShell's XML interface is built on .NET's `System.Xml` object hierarchy. You can do anything that is supported there, e.g. in this case use everything `System.Xml.XmlElement` has to offer ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement)).

Comment: I tryed it, but it didn't work...
Can you help me please?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, your variable is not called `$x`. Don't copy and paste my code. Understand and adapt it.